GA4 passing `value` parameter for an event
I'm building few tracking events which touch payment conversions, let's say this event name is event_123
in the Event Parameters I pass value (default Google parameter recognized with checkmark) and the value of this parameter is a dataLayer entry {{Data layer - paymentAmount}} which is defined in variables.
The trigger for event_123 is a custom entry in dataLayer which is named payment_completed and I additionaly filter by userRole and membership_type but this is rather less important, as the tag triggers correctly as of Tag assistant.
My problem is that the value is not passed through for this event_123 is not visble in the default reports and it does not populate the total revenue column etc. in GA4.
To make it "funnier" I created standard purchase event using very same variables/dataLayer entries... and this works, and counts those values correctly.
So the issue is when I try to pass value with a custom event.
I tried reviewing those in multiple ways but I still get back to the entry point.. as the purchase event counts correctly, and its using same values makes it so confusing.
GTM Tag assistant confirms the tag fires up properly, in the tag property it displays the value being passed correctly:
[
  {parameter: "value", parameterValue: "19.9"},
  {parameter: "currency", parameterValue: "EUR"},
  {parameter: "City_Internal", parameterValue: "Berlin"},
  {parameter: "transaction_id", parameterValue: "xxxxxxx"}
]

which has the same parameter structure as the default purchase event.
My only guess is marking something so Google recognises this is an ecommerce event but had no luck yet localising something like this. But would guess if it has ecommerce parameters passed it should recognize that.

The default reports in GA4 UI are show based on what GA4 expects, in which case the purchase event is the one expected to display transactions and associated metrics.
On the other hand, for a custom event and an associated value as a custom parameter, you can use the Explore report to make a report with that information.
